# android opengl: How to Set the background of text to the transparent?

Tags: android, text, opengl-es

The following is my code, could you tell me how to set the background of text to the transparent, I mean delete the back ground of text?

The Running result:  [image]

if(lastDrawSecond != second)
{

```
lastDrawSecond = second;

if (textureId != 0){
 gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 0);
}

gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
textureId = textures[0];
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

//ビットマップ作成
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpWidth, bmpHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);



//文字の描画

text.delete(0, text.length());
text.append("ただ今 " + calendar.getTime().toLocaleString());
paint.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
canvas.drawText(text.toString(), 10, 100, paint);
//canvas.drawText(text.toString(), 100, 10, paint);
//System.out.println("draw:"+drawX);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

bitmap.recycle();
```

}

Comment: You mean get rid of the black background?

Comment: Yes,get rid of the black background

Comment: The whole code,please visit the following link:http://blog.fujiu.jp/2011/05/android-opengl-es.html

Comment: Post your results here as an answer.
ここに答えとしてあなたの結果を投稿してください。